# How to automatically start my laptop's fans without having to run "sudo modprobe i8k"?

Tags: 13.10, fan, startup-applications

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 on a Dell Inspiron 3521 and I keep getting this error message whenever I try to use `i8kctl fan 1 1`:

```
Can't open /proc/i8k: No such file or directory
```

I can easily fix it during my current session by running in a terminal:

```
sudo modprobe i8k
```

However, I would like to know if there is a way to make my fans start on low automatically after turning my computer on, without having to enter anything in the terminal.

I am very new to Ubuntu, so I'm sorry if I don't understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

The file `/etc/modules` lists the modules that should be automatically loaded on start up.

Make sure it has this line:

```
i8k
```

and you will not need to `modprobe` that module.

Run the following command to append the above line to `/etc/modules`:

```
echo 'i8k' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Comment: Okay, I accidentally added it twice.